# Optional Any? equals to nil

Tags: swift

I have:

```
let value: Any? = myObject[keyPath: myParamKeyPath]
```

where `myParamKeyPath` refers to a `String?`.

Then, when `myParam` is supposed to be `nil`, I have:

`value == nil` returns `false`

`(value as? String?) == nil` returns `true`

Is it possible to check if `value` equals `nil` without having to cast it to a `String?` in the first place? Something like comparing it to `NSNull` maybe?

Also, I can't change the `value` type to `String?` directly as it is also used for other type in my code.

EDIT:

`(value as? String?) == nil` returns `true` is irrelevant indeed.
But I can still go print my value pointed by the keypath and it will actually be `nil`. So I still don't get why `value == nil` returns `false` when Im expecting it to be `true`...

EDIT2 with more code:

```
    let setting = appSettings.settings[indexPath.row]
    let value = appSettings[keyPath: setting.keyPath]

    let fontAwesome: FontAwesome

    switch setting.keyPath {
    case \PrinterSettings.printableImageIDs:
        fontAwesome = blablabla
    case \WeatherSettings.lockscreenImageIDs:
        fontAwesome = blablabla
    default:
        if let value = value as? FakeButtonPlacementSubSettings {
            fontAwesome = blablabla
        } else {
            fontAwesome = value != nil ? .checkSquareO : .squareO
        }
    }
```

I am expecting to get `fontAwesomeIcon = .squareO` but I am getting `checkSquareO` when the value pointed by `myObject[keyPath: myParamKeyPath]` is `String?` (it does the same for another value which is a `Bool?` later on).
I must be missing something somewhere...

EDIT 3 screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

EDIT 4 more clarification of what I'm trying to do here:

First, thank you again for your help if you get there.

Here are 2 photos about my project current design:
[image: User model]
[image: Setting usecase]

I am using with KVO in my project. I was previously using the objective-c string #keyPath for this. It was working great, but almost all my model had to be converted in @objc. So my current goal here is to remove it and switch to the new Swift 4 keypath system.

To resume: I have a user class containing lot of settings (more than on the screenshot) which can be of several type (and some custom types also).

On the other hand, I have created around 10 "setting editor view controllers": one by type of settings. I would like to use the same setting editor VC to edit each one of the same type of settings.

For example, if the setting to edit is a boolean, I would like to use the "boolean editor VC" and get my selected setting edited by the user's new choice. This is why I am using KVO system. I'm not willing to keep it if you guys have a better solution for this. It would then also get rid of my Any? == nil issue.

Comment: `(value as? String) == nil` will return true if the value cannot be cast to a String so it could either be nil or it could be an Int and that would be true.  `value == nil` should be true if it truly is a nil.  If `value == nil` is returning false then there is something in value.  I suggest you put a breakpoint and check out what it actually contains in the debugger.

Comment: Aaaaah yes thanks for the tip!! Indeed `(value as? XXX) == nil` almost always return true. Im investigating...

Comment: Edited @UpholderOfTruth

Comment: Normally I would agree @Rob, but in code `myParamKeyPath` has to have an `AnyKeyPath` type.

Comment: @Tulleb Why are you explicitly setting the value type? Try using `if let value = myObject[keyPath: myParamKeyPath] {` then option click `value` and check what is the resulting type. If you are sure it is a string try `if let value = myObject[keyPath: myParamKeyPath] as? String {`

Comment: @Tulleb that's is strange.  If value truly is nil then `value == nil` should return true.  Can you show more of the code so I can see it in context.  E.g. how are you using the check for `value == nil`

Comment: If you, for testing pupose, replace `let value: Any? = myObject[keyPath: myParamKeyPath]` with `let value: Any? = nil`, does that change the behaviour? I can not reproduce the issue. Could you print `value` for us?

Comment: @LeoDabus Im not, it was just for the example. Actually my code is `let value = myObject[keyPath: myParamKeyPath]`. If after that I am doing `if let value = value`, it actually goes inside the if and then my value becomes an `Any`, which is really weird because it is a `String?` behind it, for sure.

Comment: what happen if you do `if let value = myObject[keyPath: myParamKeyPath] as? String {`?

Comment: @Tulleb if you do `if let value = value` then all you are doing is casting from `Any?` to `Any`.  If you want to check if it is a String you need to do this `if let value = value as? String`.

Comment: More code in the EDIT2 @UpholderOfTruth. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: So I am assuming that is not complete code because fontAwesomeIcon is not used anywhere and you are 100% sure that value is nil at the line `fontAwesomeIcon = value != nil ? .checkSquareO : .squareO`

Comment: @Tulleb That's what I see: value is not a FakeButtonPlacementSubSettings type, but also it's not a nil value ) Try to use debugger and look what value of "value" at that point

Comment: I'd suggest printing `value`. I was able to manifest your behavior, where the `String?` property was `nil`, and it said `Optional(nil)`, note, not just `nil`. And where I had a `String` value, it said `Optional(Optional("foobar"))`.

Comment: @LeoDabus I doesn't go inside the `if let value = myObject[keyPath: myParamKeyPath] as? String {`, and it doesn't go into `if let value = myObject[keyPath: myParamKeyPath] as? String? {` as well... The issue must come from somewhere else. I think I should just take a break and something will jump at my eyes after some rest.

Comment: I have just added a screenshot of the debbuger. Thanks once again.

Comment: @Tulleb that is your problem right there.  Value is not nil it has an option which is nil in it.  Can you show the definition of 'appSettings'.

Comment: Your debug screen is saying that the result is `Optional(nil)`, which means you're undoubtedly looking at a `String??` value.

Comment: I cannot stress strongly enough how messed up the type `Any?` is, and how you must avoid it and convert to a more concrete type as quickly as possible if it ever appears. An `Optional` is itself of type `Any`, and also any type can be promoted to an `Optional` of itself implicitly. This means that `Any`, `Any?`, `Any??`, `Any???`, etc. are all interchangeable and may promote trivially. The entire type system goes out the window once you start involving `Any?`. What type is `appSettings` and is there *any* way to avoid its value being `Any`?

Comment: The ruby way of doing this would be

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with `appSettings`? I suspect there is a much more Swift-like way to solve this problem. Your need to special-case things with that `switch` strongly suggests a design problem here. Looking at the code, I suspect you really want an enum with associated values here rather than `as?` casting.

Comment: @Tulleb What is the type of subscript overloading? ([keyPath:])

Comment: I have added an `Edit 4` with complete description of what I am trying to do with this weird code. Thanks for your time and advices.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

```
struct S {
    let x: String?
}

let v1: Any? = S(x: "abc")[keyPath: \S.x]
print(v1 is String? && v1 == nil) // false

let v2: Any? = S(x: nil)[keyPath: \S.x]
print(v2 is String? && v2 == nil) // true
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for, but in my case the `v2 == nil` is false when it should be true. Maybe because my `AnyKeyPath` isn't explicit enough.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your code is assuming the value is `String?`, whereas it is really `String??`. I believe this stems from the use of `AnyKeyPath`:

```
struct Foo {
    let bar: String?
}

let foo = Foo(bar: "baz")

let keyPath: AnyKeyPath = \Foo.bar
print(foo[keyPath: keyPath])                        // Optional(Optional("baz"))

let keyPath2 = \Foo.bar
print(foo[keyPath: keyPath2])                       // Optional("baz")
```

I wonder if there is some way to adapt your code to use `KeyPath<T, String?>` pattern, so that, as you say, your `myParamKeyPath` really does explicitly refer to a `String?`, .e.g.:

```
let foo = Foo(bar: "baz")

let keyPath = \Foo.bar

func keyPathExperiment(object: Any, keyPath: AnyKeyPath) {
    print(object[keyPath: keyPath])
}

func keyPathExperiment2<T>(object: T, keyPath: KeyPath<T, String?>) {
    print(object[keyPath: keyPath])
}

keyPathExperiment(object: foo, keyPath: keyPath)    // Sigh: Optional(Optional("baz"))
keyPathExperiment2(object: foo, keyPath: keyPath)   // Good: Optional("baz")
```

There's not enough in your code snippet for us to see how precisely this might be adapted to your situation.

As Rob Napier said, I wonder if there might be Swiftier approaches to the problem. E.g. when I see switch statements like this, I might tend to gravitate towards `enum` pattern.

Comment: Thank you @Rob for your highlights. I have completed my explanations about what I am trying to do in my original post.